# add scoring system to bubble burst game as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

first of all thanks a lot for taking interest in my question. I am trying to modify a flash as3 bubble burst game and add a scoring system to it. I am pasting the code where it detects the bubbles group and bursting them.

```
/**
         * Checks single ball for touching another ball with the same color
         * @param   ball
         */
        private function checkHit(ball:Ball):void {
            _checkingNum++;
            ball.checked = true;
            var point:Point;
            var point2:Point;
            var d:Number;
            var scorenet:Number;
            for (var j:int = 0; j < _tabBalls.length; j++) {
                if (Ball(_tabBalls[j]).color == ball.color) {
                    if (!_tabBalls[j].checked && !inTab(_theSame, _tabBalls[j])) {
                        point = new Point(ball.x, ball.y);
                        point2 = new Point(Ball(_tabBalls[j]).x, Ball(_tabBalls[j]).y);
                        d = countD(point, point2);
                        if (d < _BALL_WIDTH + 4) {
                            _theSame.push(_tabBalls[j]);
                            checkHit(_tabBalls[j]);


                        /*score system*/

                            scorenet = scorenet + 10;
                            trace (scorenet);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            _checkingNum--;
            if (_checkingNum == 0) {
                if (_theSame.length >= 3) {
                    for (var i:int = 0; i < _theSame.length; i++) {
                        killBall(Ball(_theSame[i]));
                        Ball(_theSame[i]).kill();


                    }
                    _noeffect = 0;
                } else {
                    _noeffect++;
                    if (_noeffect >= _MAX_NO_EFFECT) {
                        _noeffect = 0;
                        addNewLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I added a variable called scorenet and later I am trying to add 10 to it each time a bubble bursts but thats obviously not working. the trace is returning a value of '0' each time a bubble bursts so if in total of say 4 bubbles get burst it returns a value of 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 . I was wondering if there was someway to trace the number of 0 it returns and then add 10 to it each time , it will work fine then. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this

```
public var scorenet:Number = 0; //as variable
```

and added the score system

/*score system*/

```
if(_checkingNum > 1 ) {
                            scorenet = scorenet + _checkingNum + 10 ;
                            _mainTimeline.scoreField.text = scorenet;

                            } else if(_checkingNum >= 4 ) {
                                scorenet = scorenet + _checkingNum + 20 ;
                                _mainTimeline.scoreField.text = scorenet;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using local variables to make scoring. local variables are lost when a method call is complete : it cannot be used to store persistent value like score. you should use member variables or static variables, which persists regardless of method calls.
2. Your calculation is NaN+10, because local variable scorenet is INITIALIZED every time checkHit() is called. so trace is showing "0". You have to deal with problem 1, or it will just be "10, 10, 10, 10..."